# An efficient, probabilistic data structure for storing relationships between elements

Tags: data-structures, data-compression, bloom-filters

I am fascinated by the bloom filter data structure. Is there a similar probabilistic data structure that can efficiently store and update the relationships between certain elements and the strength of those relationships?

Comment: If the "strength" is an integer, there is an extension of Bloom filters from sets to multisets, known as the Spectral Bloom filter. https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring05/cos598E/bib/p241-cohen-spectrum.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by the relationships between certain elements?  Can you be more specific?  Can you list the operations you want to be able to perform on such a datastructure, or the operations you want it to support?